# How to split a list of Userinput

Tags: python, list

This is my code:

```
list = []
text = input("Please give your text:")
text = str(text)
list.append(text)
list = str(list)
```

And I want to give the input, for example: abcd. Then, I want it to split it in ["a","b","c","d"]

Comment: `text = input("Please give your text:")
text = list(text)
print(text)`

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't call a variable `list` it shadows a built in keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, avoid naming your variable as `list`. You can then, split a `str` into list just by saying `list(text)`.

```
lst = []
text = input("Please give your text:")
lst.extend(list(text))
print (lst)
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Why are you creating an empty list and then `extend`ing it instead of simply creating the list directly?

Comment: I assumed, OP would be adding more items to the list :)

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
text = input("Please give your text:")
l = list(text)
print (l)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Access the characters by Index](https://www.pythonlearn.com/html-008/cfbook007.html). By iterating over the string, you can pull out each character individually. The variable `i` will be equal to index `0` to the length of `text` and you can access the character elements by index with `text[i]`. See example below:

```
user_input_as_chars = []
text = input("Please give your text:")
for i in range(0, len(text)):
    user_input_as_chars.append(text[i])
user_input_as_chars = str(list)
```

Another approach is to [traverse the Strings as an iterable](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop):

```
for char in text:
    user_input_as_chars.append(char)
```

Comment: your solution is overcode.

Comment: Maybe so, but it is arguably easier to follow for a beginner to Python. _This isn't code golf_.

Comment: It's not "let's teach antipatterns to newcomers" either. a) using `list` as a variable name. b) creating an empty list only to extend it later when it could be created entirely by a single call to `list()` (if you hadn't shadowed it). c) calling `str()` on a string. d) iterating through a string by indexing instead of item iteration.

Comment: Six lines instead of a single `l = list(input("Please give your text:"))`...

Comment: @TimPietzcker that being said, you still have valid points above. Sorry I didn't inspect BOB's code very thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = input("Please give your text:")
list.extend(list(text))
print (list)
```

Comment: This won't work. Don't shadow built-in names...